# Ubuntu 16.04 won't update anymore after kubuntu desktop installation

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I've installed the kubuntu desktop on top of my ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation, since that time my computer won't update anymore. I get errors that there are unmet dependencies, and when I try the `apt-get -f install` command, that is suggested by the terminal to solve the problem, I get

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If the Kubuntu desktop needs to be removed, I don't mind. It turned out I never use it.

I don't know how long this problem does exist, I encountered this for the first time while I was trying to install 0ad. Through the software center it didn't work, so I tried it through the terminal. It turned out that there are unmet dependencies. I tried to update/upgrade the system, to solve it, but it didn't work anymore.

Any help to fix this is appreciated!